# General term of the series - find

Tags: sequences-and-series, summation

What is the general term of the series:
$$-\frac{1}{2}-\frac{1}{3}+\frac{1}{4}+\frac{1}{5}-\frac{1}{6}-\frac{1}{7}+...$$
I think that the denominator will be $(n+1)$. But what next?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would propose $(-1)^n(\frac1{2n}+\frac1{2n+1})$.

Comment: frankly best answer, thank you

Comment: A potential gotcha is expression of a partial sum; if the last denominator of your partial sum is even, then you'll need to express the last term explicitly with this expression.  But for an infinite series this isn't an issue, of course.

Answer (score 1):

$$
(-1)^{\left \lfloor \dfrac{n+1}{2}\right \rfloor}\cdot\frac{1}{n+1}
$$

Where $n=1,2,\cdots $.

Answer (score 0):

There probably is a simpler way, but this works:

$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{\sqrt{2} \sin \left[\frac{1-2n}{4}\pi\right]}{n+1}.$$